# Using Bazel in a multi repo

Tags: bazel

When using Bazel in a multi repo environment what's the best strategy for maintaining dependency consistency?

Eg. Workspaces (individual git repos) A, B, C all depend on D. When the version of D changes, I want A, B and C to all be on the same version of D with the minimal amount of work.

Comment: probably this might help [shadowing-dependencies](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#shadowing-dependencies)

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517178/22554

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git_repository` rule in A,B, and C's `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
  name = "D",
  remote = "https://github.com/my_org/d",
  branch = "master",
)
```

Notice that the `branch` attribute is set to `master` and not some specific commit. The branch doesn't have to be master. It could be any branch.

---

If you want a way to reproduce builds,
this can be done by using `bazel sync` command.

[There is a bazel blog post](https://blog.bazel.build/2018/07/09/bazel-sync-and-resolved-file.html) with detailed explanation of the steps you need to take to have a "snapshot" file of your external workspaces (`resolved.bzl`).

You can use it either as another build artifact for future investigations or to have more control over when to update the "pointers" to the external workspace by calling `bazel sync` with `--experimental_repository_resolved_file=resolved.bzl`

Comment: In my case it would be particular versions of packages. So for instance, the branch couldn't point to master but to a particular release branch. Updating all my workspaces to point to the same, new version of a release branch with ease, is what I'm wondering about.

Comment: You can put any branch name you want. It does not have to be `master`

Comment: You can also create a variable in `starlark`, so all `git_repository` targets will point to the same branch that you only have to specify once.

Comment: Yes but as soon as I put a name on the branch it means I have to update that name everywhere anytime there's a change. Importing a bzl file with variables pointing at the latest version seems like the way to go.